# AttributeError: type object 'Tk' has no attribute 'lable'

Tags: python, tkinter

[image: скриншот кода]

Почему Tk не имеет атрибута lable?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы импортировали все файлы с библиотеки Tkinter, а это значит, что не надо добавлять класс tkinter (Tk), чтобы обратиться к нужному классу. Используйте:

```
Label(...) # без Tk
```

В вашем случае:

```
Label(frame, text='текст1', bg='gray', font=40)
```

Answer (score 0):

Наверное потому что атрибут Label называется

Comment: AttributeError: type object 'Tk' has no attribute 'label'
всё равно tk не имеет атрибут label

Comment: @Kenny А теперь с большой буквы слово Label напишите)

Comment: AttributeError: type object 'Tk' has no attribute 'Label' ))

Comment: @Kenny значит пробуйте применять атрибут Label к объекту root

Comment: @Kenny делайте как в соседнем ответе написано.